# I have country, start and end year for all baseball players. I need to know how many players per country played each year

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset with 20,000 players. Columns are birthCountry, debut_year and final_year.

```
    birthCountry debut_year  final_year
0   USA          2004        2015
1   USA          1954        1976
2   USA          1962        1971
3   USA          1977        1990
4   USA          2001        2006
```

I need to get a table as follows:

```
              1980 1981 1982
    USA         50   49   48   
    CANADA      XX   XX   XX  
    MEXICO      XX   XX   XX
    ...
```

Where each cell represents the number of players that were born in a particular country, that played during that year.

I created a nested list, containing all years that each player played. The length of this list is the same as the length of the df. In the df, I created one additional column per year and I tried to add 1 for each player/year combination.

The idea was to use this to create a groupby or pivot_table

```py
# create a list of years
years = list(range(min(df['debut_year'].values),max(df['final_year'].values)+1))

# create a list of countries
countries = df.birthCountry.unique()

# add columns for years
for n in range(1841,2019): #years are from 1841 to 2018
    df[n] = ''
# now I have one additional column for every year. A lot of new empty columns

# temporary lists
templist = list(range(0,len(df)))

# every element of the following list contains all the years each player played
templist2 = []
for i in templist:
    templist2.append(list(range(int(df.iloc[i,1]),int(df.iloc[i,2])))) 

# add 1 if the player played that year
for i in range(len(df)):
    for j in templist2[i]:
        df.iloc[i][j] = 1
```

I run for some time and then nothing changed in the original dataframe.

Probably you can find a better more elegant solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To limit the size of the example, I created the following source DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[ 1, 'USA', 1974, 1978 ], [ 2, 'USA', 1976, 1981 ],
    [ 3, 'USA', 1975, 1979 ], [ 4, 'USA', 1977, 1980 ],
    [ 5, 'Mex', 1976, 1979 ], [ 6, 'Mex', 1978, 1980 ]],
    columns=['Id', 'birthCountry', 'debut_year', 'final_year'])
```

The fists step of actual computation is to create a *Series* containing
years in which each player was active:

```
years = df.apply(lambda row: pd.Series(range(row.debut_year,
    row.final_year + 1)), axis=1).stack().astype(int).rename('year')
```

The second step is to create an auxiliary DataFrame - a join of
`df.birthCountry` and `years`:

```
df2 = df[['birthCountry']].join(years.reset_index(level=1, drop=True))
```

And the last step is to produce the actual result:

```
df2.groupby(['birthCountry', 'year']).size().rename('Count')\
    .unstack().fillna(0, downcast='infer')
```

For the above test data, the result is:

```
year          1974  1975  1976  1977  1978  1979  1980  1981
birthCountry                                                
Mex              0     0     1     1     2     2     1     0
USA              1     2     3     4     4     3     2     1
```

I think, my solution is more "pandasonic" than the other, proposed earlier
by *Remy*.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to come up with the following solution if I understand the structure of your `df` variable correctly. I made a dictionary list (using a smaller range of years) with the same structure for my example:

```
df = [{'birthCountry': 'USA', 'debut_year': 2012, 'final_year': 2016},
      {'birthCountry': 'CANADA', 'debut_year': 2010, 'final_year': 2016},
      {'birthCountry': 'USA', 'debut_year': 2012, 'final_year': 2017},
      {'birthCountry': 'CANADA', 'debut_year': 2012, 'final_year': 2017},
      {'birthCountry': 'MEXICO', 'debut_year': 2012, 'final_year': 2016}]

countries = {}
for field in df:
    if field['birthCountry'] not in countries.keys():
        countries[field['birthCountry']] = {year: 0 for year in range(2010, 2019)}
    for year in range(field['debut_year'], field['final_year']):
        countries[field['birthCountry']][year] += 1
```

Comment: Thanks Remy, your solution worked using only few lines of code. Valdi_Bo solution gave me a somehow nice formatted table, that's why I chose his answer as the accepted one. Thanks anyway @Remy